# Multi ImageView e EditText Upload via Parse Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm trying to register multiple products at once with dynamic layout, when it's in the single registration option of a product it works normally, but when it's the multiple option it doesn't load all items, can someone help me please
[Imagem do Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk8fw.jpg)

```js
//Forma única
            parseObject.put("titulo_multipla", 0);
            parseObject.put("promocao_multipla", 0);
            parseObject.put("produto_servico", tituloPromocao.getText().toString());
            parseObject.put("preco", precoPromocao.getText().toString());
            parseObject.put("datainicio", startDateString);
            parseObject.put("datafim", endDateString);
            parseObject.put("imagem", arquivoParse);
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the problem and the code that you are using?

Comment: I decided to open a new post more explanatory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72353551/dynamic-upload-multi-images-and-descriptions-parse-server-android  Thanks